# Custom form action across two-page form

Tags: jquery, forms, action

I have a website client who uses Salesforce WebToLead. It's just a simple form process that captures field data via a custom Salesforce URL in the form's action. My problem is, the client wants a 2-page form. I can make the 2-page form, but where do I put the action? Complicating things, this has to simultaneously send an email of form data to the client's email address.

I've tried stuff like this:

```
onsubmit: "$("#777").attr("action",
  "https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8");$submit();"
```

But no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by 2-page form? Do you have to do a redirect between these pages?

Comment: Can have one form wrap numerous "pages" ...like tabs...so it's really not clear enough what the issue is without more information. Not sure what `onsubmit` is part of but it most probably needs to be an anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written your full code or explained what is a two page form (seperate pages, or just hide-show some boxes on the screen), so I will just try to point you to a direction.

If you're going to redirect between the first and second parts of your form, you can use localStorage and clear data when you submit on the second page. User will fill the first part of the form, click "Next". OnClick function of that "Next" button will first save all the form input values to a localStorage key and redirect to the second page. On the second page you'll have your submit. User will fill the rest of the form and click "Submit" button. Submit function will first read the data from localStorage and save them to a local var. With the second page's values, combine the two page's values on an object and send your data along with your post. That simple...

If you don't need to redirect on "Next" button click, you can use that button to hide the first page, and show the second page. When hiding the first form, collect the input values on a local variable, and show the second page. When your user finishes filling the form and clicks on Submit button, combine the second page's values with first page's and send the data along with your post.

Maybe I didn't understand your question. If that's the case, feel free to provide more information.